# Add ongoing call to connection service

Tags: android

Using the new ConnectionService API from Google, I found out that not every phone has the UI to do video calling, meaning that I have to fallback to my own video call implementation for these phones.

Reading from Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html):

> When there are no more live calls, telecom will unbind from the
>   ConnectionService.

This means that if there is no ongoing call with my ConnectionService implementation when I'm intercepting an incoming/outgoing video call on my own and that I call [addExistingConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html#addExistingConnection(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20android.telecom.Connection)) on my ConnectionService, the TelecomManager gets notified, but the TelecomService behind the TelecomManager will not bind back to my ConnectionService. It means that if I downgrade to audio and that I call [showInCallScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#showInCallScreen(boolean)), nothing will happen, even if my ConnectionService does contain the ongoing call.

In another use case, if I already have an ongoing audio call using ConnectionService and then I do an outgoing video call that I add to my ConnectionService, TelecomManager will get notified and I will be able to swap between my two calls in the native UI.

Is there a call missing after addExistingConnection to have the TelecomService bind back to my ConnectionService implementation?

```
if (action.equals(ADD_CALL_ACTION) && isInitialized) {
    final String sessionId = myIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SESSION_ID);
    final PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = TelecomIntegrationHelper.getPhoneAccountHandle(context);

    addExistingConnection(phoneAccountHandle, createOngoingConnection(sessionId));
    getTelecomManager().showInCallScreen(false);
}
```